# Checking inner workings of a statement of linear algebra using Mathematica

Tags: linear-algebra, estimation, experimental-mathematics

Suppose $A,B \in M_{n}(\Bbb{R})$ such that $A = \left[C_{1}\middle|\frac{I}{0\dots0}\right], B= \left[C_{2}\middle|\frac{I}{0\dots0}\right]$ , where $A$ and $B$ have different first columns (represented as $C_{1}, C_{2}$).

Assumption:

Let $\lambda_{i}, i=1, \ldots, n$ denote the eigenvalues  of $AB^2$. Then we have the condition that $|\lambda_{i}|<1 \, \forall i$.

Let $\beta_{i}, i=1, \ldots, n$ denote the eigenvalues  of $A^2B$. Then we have the condition that $|\beta_{i}|<1 \, \forall i$.

Statement:

Then I have an intuition that $\textbf{ $\det(AB+A+I) < 0$ and $\det(BA+B+I)<0$ is not possible.}$

Is there a computational way/ approach to verify this?

I just have a thought if Mathematica can be used to prove or disprove this statement or can be used to check the inner mechanisms of the statement?

Some thoughts:

After a bit of experimentation, I found that

$\det(AB + A + I) = \det(BA+B+I) + e_{1}^{T} adj(A^2 +A+I) \xi$ , where $\xi = C_{1}-C_{2}, and $${e_{1}}^{T} = (1,0, 0,\ldots,0)$.

Not sure if this can provide some hint on why the main statement holds?

Comment: Yes, I should have been more clear. We assume: all the absolute value of eigenvalues of $AB^2, A^2B$ are less than $1$. Under such an assumption we have to show that $\det(AB+A+I)<0$ and $\det(BA+B+I) < 0$ is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

*Not a full answer, just a starting point for OP to test the statement using randomly generated matrices. This could potentially be used to disprove the statement (find a counterexample).*

OP could use something like this

```
(* this can be adjusted *)
n=2;

(* generates one such matrix
   note that we use machine numbers, one could use rational numbers *)
randX:=ArrayFlatten[{{RandomReal[{-5,5},{n,1}],
          Join[IdentityMatrix[n-1],{ConstantArray[0,n-1]}]}}]//N;

(* test claim for one A and one B *)
randTest:=With[{A=randX,B=randX,id=IdentityMatrix[n]},
             And[ And@@Thread[Abs[Eigenvalues[A.B.B]]<1],
                  And@@Thread[Abs[Eigenvalues[A.A.B]]<1],
                  Det[A.B+A+id]<0,
                  Det[B.A+B+id]<0]];
```

To test many times, one can use

```
SeedRandom[1];
Or@@Table[randTest,{100000}]
(* False *)
```

which means that in this run at least, no pair of matrices was found that would contradict OPs intuition. OP might want to play with `n`, and the setting for `RandomReal` above.

Comment: Yes, this can be a starting point..but I actually wonder why it is true..and to look into it maybe it has to be looked upon computationally..this might next give an idea about the proof..